# It is acceptable to an entity directly mentioned in viewmodel and the views?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I am developing a multi-layered, using ASP.NET MVC 3 and Entity Framework. I have an entity called "Site" which belongs to the domain layer. It is acceptable to mention directly in a domain entity viewmodel and the views?

ViewModel

```
public IList <Domain.Entities.Site> Sites;
```

View

```
foreach (var item in Model.Sites)
{
...
}
```

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be "acceptable" - if that's the object closest to the presentation layer with that data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically not. The point of a ViewModel is to abstract only the information needed from the Model.

You should have a ViewModel that also corresponds to the Site model.

So you would have:

```
// assuming the Domain model is what we're talking about
public class DomainViewModel
{
    public IList<SiteViewModel> Sites { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would not be a rework because "SiteViewModel" would have the same properties of the entity?

Comment: @AdrianoSilva - It may for the time being, but that isn't always a guarantee. The point of separating the two is so that you only pass necessary information to the View. The View may not need all members of Site.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is perfectly acceptable to reference domain entities in your view. If you don't need to transform any of the information in the domain entity for your view then abstracting it away using a ViewModel is superfluous.

As you will likely find there are differing opinions on this subject but what it really comes down to is whether abstracting away the domain entity is adding any value. Creating a ViewModel will add some future flexibility and maybe for you that is enough reason to justify it. If that is the case then by all means do it. But do not feel you have to out of fear of violating MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Binding directly to a model is a short term solution. Better to have a viewmodel wrap your model in case you need to bind to other properties that are not directly model related. i.e. bool CanDelete, bool IsEnabled...

Answer (score 0):

In general, no.

If this is a QUICK and BASIC application, then a reluctant sure.

Anything beyond that you are shooting yourself in the foot and the general accepted pattern is to use ViewModels instead to hold all the data you need (which includes SelectList data, etc as opposed to using ViewBag.

Btw on ViewBag, avoid that too:
http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/12/stop-using-viewbag-in-most-places.html